# which.max() does not return NA

Tags: r

I have a bunch of ordered vectors containing numbers between 0 and 1. I need to find the index of the first element over a certain value r:

```
x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.8)
which.max(x >= 0.4)
[1] 3  # This is exactly what I need
```

Now if my target value is over the maximum value in the vector, which.max() returns 1, which 
can be confused with the "real" first value:

```
which.max(x >= 0)
[1] 1
which.max(x >= 0.9) # Why?
[1] 1
```

How could I modify this expression to get an NA as a result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `which()` and return the first element:

```
which(x > 0.3)[1]
[1] 3

which(x > 0.9)[1]
[1] NA
```

---

To understand why `which.max()` doesn't work, you have to understand how R coerces your values from numeric to logical to numeric.

```
x > 0.9
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

as.numeric(x > 0.9)
[1] 0 0 0 0

max(as.numeric(x > 0.9))
[1] 0

which.max(as.numeric(x > 0.9))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and for the explanation!